# Adding a new item to an unordered list using jQuery with no IDs and too many classes

Tags: jquery, html, dom, append

I need to use a custom.js override file to add a new link to an unordered list on three pages. I must use jquery, per the systems requirements, and finding a way to select and insert is really numbing my brain.

Here is the menu block itself:

```
<div class="nav-block nav-block-logo">
  <div class="nav-block-body">
    <div class="nav-block-content">
      <div class="logo">
    <a href="/"><img src="logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <ul>
      <li class="active">
      <a href="/contact-us/">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/contact-us/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last-child">
      <a href="/contact-us/facilities-and-directions">Facilities &amp; Directions</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" class="bookmark-share addthis_button">Bookmark &amp; Share</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to add a new li link at the end. I've tried after() and append(), and neither have worked. I was told I may need to target the h2 and check to see if the title is "contact us" or not. Not sure how to do this either.

I am relatively new to jquery, and this was kinda dumped on me at last minute. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used class targeting. It's pretty reliable compared to looking for content, and certainly faster. I also made sure to update your last-child classes.

```
var $list = $(".nav-block .nav-block-content ul:first");
$list.find(".last-child").removeClass("last-child"); 
var $li = $("<li>", {"class": "last-child"}).html('<a href="#">Our Blog</a>');
$list.append($li);
```

With regards to the selector, I put in the easiest one but you can be more specific if necessary. For example:

```
var $list = $(".nav-block .nav-block-content ul:first")
```

Comment: Looks solid. I tried it. Didn't work. :( I have no idea why I can't get something so simple to work.

Comment: Typo on line 3, I fixed it, give it another shot. I hate handling strings in JS.

Comment: `var $list = $(".nav-block .nav-block-content ul:first")
 $list.find(".last-child").removeClass("last-child");
 var $li = $("<li>", {"class": "last-child"}).html('<a href="">Our Blog</a>');
 $list.append($li);`  Worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` selector:

```
var $li = $('<li>', {
  'id': 'id',
  'class': 'class'
}).html('<a href="herf">text</a>');

​$('h2:contains("Contact Us")').siblings('ul').append($li)​​​;    ​
// $('.nav-block-logo ul)').append($li)​​​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fj2K5/

Comment: I don't think you should use his proposed solution. Why not just target the list based on class? Content is subject to change.

Comment: I have, there's nothing there saying you can't use selector targeting

Comment: hmm, interesting looks fine +1 bruver, unless I missed anything. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your new `li` element is a DOM object:

```
$('div.nav-block-content ul').append(newLI);
```

will add it as the last child of the `ul`.

Here's a fiddle (which also demos how to move the `last-child` class to the correct element): http://jsfiddle.net/EwMSB/

Comment: It works in the fiddle I set up. Are you wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` function?